# New Relic causing our applications to fall over

Tags: c#, asp.net, newrelic

We have installed New Relic on 3 servers, and had to turn them off on our 2 higher load servers within 30 minutes of agents being installed. (The third server has low load, so any issues New Relic is causing is hard to spot)

The symptoms are ever increasing delays in processing the requests, these symptoms vanish as soon as the .net agent is disabled, they come back when re-enabling it.

The only change to the config is the application name from 'My Application' to something relevant, and the adding of a proxy.

Any ideas what may be causing this??

---

Added: The servers are all Windows Server 2008 or 2012, 24 core Xeon Machines with at least 32gb of ram. They are running IIS 7.5, hosting .net 3.5 applications using MVC 2, or as WCF services.

Comment: Do your servers meet the [compatibility / requirements](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/new-relic-for-net)?  What kind of web app is it (framework)?  Also, (and this is going to sound like a really lame question, but) does New Relic indicate where the slowdowns are specifically?  It is monitoring / logging software, after all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to programming per se.

Comment: The servers are all Windows Server 2008 or 2012, 24 core Xeon Machines with at least 32gb of ram. They are running IIS 7.5, hosting .net 3.5 applications using MVC 2, or as WCF services.

Answer (score 0):

The New Relic .NET agent requires a "cold start" time for the profiler to load into your IIS worker process.  This happens each time an app pool recycles, so if yours recycle frequently, response times will most likely suffer.

If that's not the case, please file a support ticket at support.newrelic.com - we would like to get some more specifics and work with you directly to resolve this issue.